# Lucene.net on a central server

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have a problem finding references to this subject and would appreciate some help.

We have an application that uses a central sql server and a local lucene. Since the data is synchronized we wish to put the lucene on the same machine as the sql server and access it remotely. I was looking for documentation and examples on how to do it in C# but found only in java.

Comment: Hi,

Can someone help me with examples? or a bit more detailed documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which is a search server built on top of Lucene. You can install it on your central server; and query it using http. SOLR only exist as a Java implementation, but this shouldn't be a problem because it is a standalone server that you can query remotely.

There is also an open source project, [Solr.NET](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) which provides a nice .NET interface to querying the server - so you don't have to mock around with http requests.

Comment: SOLR is definitely the solution with the biggest community and documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Do you know which class should I use, or do you have an example code?

Answer (score 0):

It's been two years, but I still feel I owe you an update.
This project had lots of cycles. At the beginning we wrote a simple WCF server that was not well written but served the purpose for that phase (R&D). When moving to tests we needed something more scalable. For a while we used to save sessions indexes as blobs on sql server, but after awhile we moved to [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

Unfortunately, this project was then frozen, so I can't say how was this infrastructure but it seemed like a good solution.